# Is the point spectrum always countable?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I have this very simple question.

**Premise**: Let $A$ be a linear densely defined symmetric/self-adjoint operator in a complex separable Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ (typical example in Quantum Mechanics).

**Definition**: The set $\sigma_{\text{pp}}:=\{z| z\in\mathbb C,~ \nexists \left(A-z I\right)^{-1}:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H\} $ is called *the pure point spectrum of A*. (Definition from Stone, M.H. "Linear Transformations in Hilbert Space and their Applications to Analysis", AMS, 1932, page 129.)

Then is the following result true?

**Statement**: $\sigma_{\text{pp}}$ is countable (or an empty set).

Kindly provide me with a counterexample if not true, or with a rigorous proof if true.

Thank you,

Comment: What you have written sounds like an imprecise definition of the entire spectrum, not of the pure point spectrum.

Comment: I copied that from my QM notes. Here is the definition from Blanchard & Bruening: $\sigma_{\text{pp}} (A) = \{\lambda\in\sigma (A)|\text{Ker}\left(A-\lambda I\right)\neq 0_{\mathcal H}\}$. So it is really the same.

Comment: How is that the same?

Comment: @DanielC: no, it's definitely not the same.

Comment: My mind is blown, since I have three definitions: the one in Blanchard & Brüning, then the one in V. Moretti: the point spectrum of A, $\sigma_p (A)$, made by complex numbers $\lambda$ for which $A−\lambda I$ is not injective. And the definition in Prugovecki which is my definition.

Comment: The Prugovecki definition which I used is also in M.H. Stone 1932 on page 129. Theorem 4.2 by Stone is exactly Blanchard & Brüning's definition. Then the defintion of Stone is stated as the same with the definition of Moretti (and R&S, Vol.1) because "The Transformation $T_l$ (nb $T_l = T-l1$) will fail to have an inverse if and only if there exist distinct elements $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $\mathcal D$ such that $T_l f_1 = T_l f_2, ~ T_l (f_1-f_2) = 0$."

Comment: @DanielC: yes, that's the definition of the point spectrum. Which is **not** what you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Av=\lambda v$ and $Aw=\mu w$ with $v,w$ unit vectors and $\lambda\ne\mu$, then (using that $A$ is selfadjoint)
$$
\lambda\langle v,w\rangle=\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,Aw\rangle=\mu\langle v,w\rangle
$$
(note that $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R$). So $\langle v,w\rangle=0$. Thus the eigenspaces corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. If $H$ is separable, it can only have countably many pairwise orthogonal subspaces, so the set of eigenvalues of $A$ is at most countable.

Comment: So it's essential in the proof that the operator be self-adjoint. OK, I understand the argument. Is the continuous spectrum of a self-adjoint operator always uncountable?

Comment: @DanielC you should probably ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @DanielC: if you ask another quesiton, I'll answer. Meanwhile, no, the continuous spectrum can even consists of a single point.

Comment: Just done it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401536/is-the-continous-spectrum-of-a-self-adjoint-operator-always-uncountable