# Is the continous spectrum of a self-adjoint operator always uncountable?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

This is the natural continuation to this [Is the point spectrum always countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395362/is-the-point-spectrum-always-countable/3395685)

**Premise**: Let $T$ be a linear densely defined symmetric/self-adjoint operator in a complex separable Hilbert space $\frak{H}$ (typical example in Quantum Mechanics).

**Definition**: Let $T_l :=T-lI$. The set of points $B(T)$ such that $T_{l}^{-1}$ exists and is an unbounded linear transformation with domain $\frak{R}_l$ everywhere dense in $\frak{H}$ is called the continous spectrum of $T$.

Is the following true?

**Statement**: The continous spectrum of $T$ is either uncountable of the empty set.

*P.S. The definition I took is from M.H. Stone ""Linear Transformations in Hilbert Space and their Applications to Analysis", AMS, 1932, page 129.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuous spectrum can be finite, even when $T$ is bounded.

Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis of a separable Hilbert space $H$. Define a bounded operator $T:H\to H$ by
$$
Te_n=\tfrac1n\,e_n. 
$$
So $T$ is the selfadjoint operator that with respect to the aforementioned basis is diagonal with diagonal $\{1,\tfrac12,\tfrac13,\ldots\}$. The spectrum of $T$ is 
$$
\sigma(T)=\{0\}\cup\{\tfrac1n:\ n\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
Each $\tfrac1n$ is an eigenvalue. And the continuous spectrum of $T$ is $\{0\}$, since $T$ is injective with dense range.

Tweaking of the above example allows you to produce examples where the continuous spectrum is any finite (or countable, bounded, and discrete) subset of $\mathbb C$. Concretely, write $T_0$ for the operator above. Given $\{q_n\}\subset\mathbb C$ bounded, let 
$$
T=\bigoplus_n (q_n I+ T_0).
$$
Then $\sigma(T)=\overline{\bigcup_n\sigma(q_n I+T_0)}=\overline{\bigcup_n\{q_n\}}$.